# @Inject something inside a @Named @SessionScoped bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, managed-bean

Maybe I'm getting old but... I really can't figure how to inject a business logic class inside a jsf managed bean controller, here's how the controller bean is now:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ImportazioneController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String stato;

    private Retriever<Marchio> retriever;

    public ImportazioneController() { }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.stato = "";
        retriever = new WSRetrieverMarchi();
    }
}
```

My interface is:

```
public interface Retriever<T> {

    public List<T> retrieve();
}
```

The desired implementation to inject is:

```
public class WSRetrieverMarchi implements Retriever<Marchio> {

    @Override
    public List<Marchio> retrieve() {
        // do things...
    }

}
```

I'd really love to @Inject the *retriever* but I keep getting errors.

I know this isn't the CDI way, too.
If you can help me with a new technique, I would really appreciate that.
Thank you.

Comment: What errors are you receiving with which code?